# Why is my callback parameter undefined?

Tags: javascript, sorting, callback, undefined

I've tried defining the callback function without the context:

`return callback(value, index, list).sort()`

But this doesn't work either. Not sure why I am getting the error: "ReferenceError: value is not defined"

```
var arr = [1,4,2,8,3];

var mySort = function(list, callback, context) {
    if (typeof callback !== "function") 
        return list.sort(); 
    else if (typeof callback === "function") {
        return callback.call(context, value, index, list).sort();
    }
}; 

var cb = function(num) {num*3;};

mySort(arr, cb);

//console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Where is `value` and `index` in `callback.call(context, value, index, list).sort();` ?

Comment: Also, note that calling your `cb` function (`var cb = function(num) {num*3;};`) is a no-op. You probably meant to return something there.

Comment: It's hard to find your goal. Your function is called with missing arguments and probably should return a number that you couldn't sort anyway.

Comment: As it is, this code looks really random.

Comment: Ahh sorry. I'm just writing some code to try and get some practice with callbacks that have multiple function arguments (some used, some not). The callback function was supposed to return the arr having all the values multiplied by 3. I totally overlooked that. The mySort function was supposed to take that modified arr and sort it. I've fixed the problems, but it doesnt sort quite right. It returns: `[12, 24, 3, 6, 9]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never defined the variables `value` and`index` in the `mySort` function.
Also, the `cb` function is missing a return statement.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing in cb, which is identified as a function, gets processed as such and tries to call

```
return callback.call(context, value, index, list).sort();
```

The variable **value** (in this context) doesn't exist, which leads to the reference error.